# Webpack 5: Can't view website on devices connected to same network

Tags: webpack

Am trying to create webpack 5 boilerplate. I cannot view website on my mobile phone during development.

1. Both my computer and mobile phone are connected to same wifi network.
2. Am entering my computers ipv4 address followed by port number in my mobile browser.

Here is my webpack.config.js

```js
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: './script/app.js',

  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
  },

  mode: 'development',

  devtool: 'eval-source-map',

  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    port: 8000,
    hot: true,
    host: '0.0.0.0',
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.html$/i,
        loader: 'html-loader',
      },

      {
        test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
        use: [
          // Creates `style` nodes from JS strings
          'style-loader',
          // Translates CSS into CommonJS
          'css-loader',
          // Compiles Sass to CSS
          'sass-loader',
        ],
      },

      {
        test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|jpeg|gif)$/i,
        type: 'asset/resource',
      },
    ],
  },

  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './index.html',
      filename: 'index.html',
      favicon: './img/favicon.png',
    }),
  ],
};
```

Comment: You probably need to disable your firewall

Answer (score 0):

You may need to disable host checking with `disableHostCheck: true`